# Input mask with JQuery and regexp

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm looking for a Javascript or JQuery solution (client side) to :

- Mask input: prohibit the user to enter an illegal character

  - Accept regexp like `^[-+]?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?`
- Format the input

  - thousands separator= `,`
  - decimal separator= `.`

For example, I want `1234.56` to be display (*change to*) '1,234.56`.

[Masked Input Plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) can't allow the formatting (I can't tell it `[0-9]+` before the decimal separator).

[meioMask](http://www.meiocodigo.com/projects/meiomask/) allows `999.999.999.999,99` format, but the value is converted to string. The binding with Double in Java fails.

Do you have proposals, areas of research?

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but perhaps may make your life easier!  Check out: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/numberformatter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the advice of *Ayman Safadi* and I've used plugins.jquery.com/project/numberformatter to format and parse the input.

I store the value entered in the `alt` field and restore to the `value` when the user focus (and format `onBlur`).

This solution does not block the entry (eg prevent type a letter in an amount). Any other ideas should be appreciate.